# Cocoon and Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: xml, forms, pdf, livecycle, apache-cocoon

We have an application where a set of complex **PDF forms** are being produced with **Adobe LiveCycle platform and Designer** (version 8.2), and served by a Java-based web application to the end-user client, where are displayed inline. 
These forms come with application logic expressed by some Javascript validation controls, as well as with showing/hiding conditions evaluated dynamically as the user compiles the various form fields.
Once the PDF forms are saved, the underlying **XML data** is extracted and persisted, serving as a basis for subsequent operations.

We have been asked to find an alternative to this general architecture, centered around Adobe LiveCycle technologies, while at the same time keeping both the XML data format (and the XSD Schema defining it) as the **model** around which build **HTML forms**, instead of PDF ones, and the level of application logic currently expressed in PDF forms.

Having this strong requirement around XML format we have start looking for an alternative letting us produce the forms and having *as few intermediate layers as possible* in our revised application *between the starting XML data model and the final HTML forms*.

We have came across [**Cocoon Forms**](https://cocoon.apache.org/2.2/blocks/forms/1.0/489_1_1.html), a "block" (i.e. a module) of the [**Cocoon Framework**](https://cocoon.apache.org/); and it looks as an interesting possible solution, sharing some similarities with Adobe LiveCycle platform:

- strong focus on XML-related technologies
- XML itself is used to define both the **form model** as well as its representation with the **form template**, both DSLs based on XML
- possibility to express validation logic between the various form elements
- seamless integration between the forms client and server sides

Does anyone out there has any experience with Cocoon Forms? 
If so would anyone please let us know if, in regard to our breafly summarized scenario, *could it be considered a viable solution*?

Thanx in advance!